# CSS: set color for selected row in a table

Tags: css, colors, css-tables

I need to add the following feature to my table:

When the user clicks on a row (selects it), the row is marked with the color `#FFCF8B` (the same as `hover`). I tried `#newspaper-b` `tbody tr.selected td`, but it does not work.

```
   #newspaper-b {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-color: #B7DDF2;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
        width: 480px;
    }
    #newspaper-b th {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EBF4FB;
        border-color: lightgray;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    }
    #newspaper-b tbody tr td {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    }
    #newspaper-b td {
        border-top: 1px dashed #FFFFFF;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #newspaper-b tbody tr:hover td {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
        color: #000000;
    }
    #newspaper-b tbody tr.selected td {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

Comment: Ummm... you do know you need JavaScript to add the `.selected` class to the table on click, don't you?

Comment: Could you please write an example?

Comment: Do you use vanilla JS, or jQuery or a similar JS library?

Comment: Misleading question. Implies the solution involves a css selector and not javascript

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to add a .selected class to your clicked row you need a bit of JavaScript.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/KzVfy/

I used jQuery for the example, so there is very little code:

```
$("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});​
```

Of course, it can be done without using any library if you don't wish to include jQuery.

---

Just for variation, I did another version. **This one uses no library** (no jQuery, no Mootools, no YUI, no Dojo, and so on...) and selects multiple rows. Can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/nY5jj/ with a variation that unselelects a selected row when clicking on it again http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/nY5jj/1/

The JavaScript is:

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
    trs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){this.className += " selected";});
}​
```

To unselect a selected row when clicking on it a second time :

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
    trs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var cn = this.className, thc = " selected", start_idx = cn.indexOf(thc);
        if(start_idx == -1) cn += thc;
        else cn = cn.replace(thc,"");
        this.className = cn;
    });
}​
```

Comment: This will work — so long as @Klausos has jQuery loaded in. ;)

Comment: +1 but your variation that unselects the selected row was not working for me, I used this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153194/how-to-remove-class-from-siblings-of-an-element-without-jquery

Answer (score 5):

With `CSS` i think you can't do this. You can use `jQuery`. I wrote fast basic example(but there is more ways how you can do it):

```
 <table class="tab" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>lol</td>
      <td>lol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lol</td>
      <td>lol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lol</td>
      <td>lol</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Add to your `CSS` file this:

```
tr.clicked {
      background-color: #abc;
}
```

Add this `jQuery` code:

```
$('.tab tr').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    });
```

When you click on row in your `table`, `jQuery` will add `background-color` for your row, click again, class will be removed.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle using dojo.  Same concepts that everyone else has mentioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/SG9dp/

NOTE: I allowed multiple rows to be selected.  Question didn't state the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    marging: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initSelection()">

<table id="myTable" onkeydown="fn">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>

var row = 0;
var cell = 0
var selectedStyle = "5px solid #c68305";
var deleSelectedStyle ="2px solid #000000" ;
function initSelection() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTable");
  x.rows[row].cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;

}
document.addEventListener('keydown',fn);
function fn(event){
  console.log(event.keyCode);
  var x = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var prev = x.rows[row];
  var cur = null;
  var next = null;
  if(event.keyCode ==40){
    if(prev){
      prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = deleSelectedStyle;
    }
     row++;
     cur = x.rows[row];
     if(cur){
        cur.cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;
     }else{
      row =0;
      cur = x.rows[row];
      cur.cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;
     }
   }else if(event.keyCode==38){
    prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = deleSelectedStyle;
     row--;
     if(row<0){
      row = x.rows.length-1;
     }
     x.rows[row].cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;
   }else if(event.keyCode==39){
    prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = deleSelectedStyle;
     cell++;
     next   = prev.cells.item(cell);
     if(next){
        prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;
     }else{
        cell = 0;
        prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;
     }
   }else if(event.keyCode==37){
      prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = deleSelectedStyle;
     cell--;
      if(cell<0){
      cell = prev.cells.length-1;
     }
     prev.cells.item(cell).style.border = selectedStyle;
   }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```