# How to remove class from siblings of an element without JQuery?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding a class to an element and want to remove it from siblings. In JQuery it is simple, but how to do it the best way in plain JS?
Here is an example of my code.

```
<div class="controllers">
  <span id='one' class='active'></span>
  <span id='two'></span>
  <span id='three'></span>
</div>

firstBtn.onclick = function() {
  slides[0].className = 'slide active';
  this.className = 'active';
};
```

Comment: have a look at this: [classlist](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use loop inside click event to remove `active` class from all elements and then again set it on clicked element.

```js
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.controllers span');
for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = function() {
    var c = 0;
    while (c < el.length) {
      el[c++].className = 'slide';
    }
    el[i].className = 'slide active';
  };
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="controllers">
  <span id='one' class='active'>Lorem</span>
  <span id='two'>Lorem</span>
  <span id='three'>Lorem</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

A generic function to set only one active element would be:

```
const setActive = el => {
    [...el.parentElement.children].forEach(sib => sib.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active')
    }
```

In your example:

```
let spans = [...document.body.querySelectorAll('.controllers > span')];
spans.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => setActive(el)))
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j1qguac/

Update: At one point, browsers expected `Array.from(el.parentElement.children)` instead of `[...el.parentElement.children]`. Both are now supported, but if you start a row with a bracket, the previous row needs a semicolon. (eg `a = b \n [1].map...` will be treated as `a = (b[1]).map...`.

Answer (score 3):

To remove a class from sibling

```
var el = document.getElementById( "two" );
var one = el.previousSibling();
one.classList.remove("active");
```

use [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) or [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to traverse to it, and use [classList.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) to remove a class.

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get it work with previousElementSibling.
But it doesn't actually work if I pick third span after the first or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove a class from an element siblings**

```
let elem = document.getElementById('id');
let siblings = elem.parentElement.children;
  for(let sib of siblings) {
      sib.classList.remove('active')
      }
```

Comment: Nice and clean and simple, best answer here for current (2024) JS.